# print 1 slide on 2 pages

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Hi I have a powerpoint slide, that I need to have printed in 2 halves.

It's an A1, slide, and I want it to print on 2xA3, since I only have cardboard on A3, and I don't want the entire slide to downscale.

Edit: 
My issue is, that the first slide is supposed to be printed in A1, and the following are A3, but I need the ratios to be the same, because there are figures across the slides that need to be the same size when printed.

How can I set that up?

Comment: If you don't want to downscale then A1 (594 x 841 mm) = 4 x A3 (297 x 420 mm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is as follows.

First print the slide to PDF, using any PDF writer. In PowerPoint 2010 (don't know about earlier versions) you can also select PDF format when you do a "Save As".

Then, open the file in Acrobat 10 or later, or use a PDF viewer such as PDF-Xchangeviewer. When you go to print, you can set the Scaling to "Tile pages". That will then print as many pages as necessary to fit the entire A1 image. Do note that most printers have non-printing margins that are typically 5 mm for laser printers, so you will have to trim the edges unless you don't mind gaps between the tiles.

As David Postill mentioned in his comment, an A1 sheet equates to 4 A3 sheets (or 2 A2 sheets)

Comment: In Acrobat Reader (2018) click "Poster" on the print dialog.